# Are there non trivial maps from $H\mathbb{Z}$ to $MGL$?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, stable-homotopy, cobordism, motivic-homotopy

Let $k$ be a field of characteristic $0$. Let us denote by $\mathbf{1}_{k}$ the sphere spectrum. Let $MGL$ be the algebraic cobordism spectrum.

We have the following diagram

$$H\mathbb{Z}\leftarrow \mathbf{1}_{k}\rightarrow MGL$$

My question is the following:

> Are there non trivial maps $H\mathbb{Z}\to MGL$ such that the above triangle commutes?

Comment: What kind of maps are you interested in? If you want maps of algebras, [this question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/235033/is-mgl-an-h-mathbbz-algebra?rq=1) shows it is impossible.

Comment: Dear @DenisNardin. I'm just interested in maps of spectra.

Comment: I don’t think this is true classically: if such a map did exist, HZ would be a retract of MU, but every k-invariant of k(n) is given by the nth Milnor primitive. There is probably a contradiction here. (Come to think of it, having a retraction may let you run the HZ-algebra argument, rather than knowing something about k-invariants.) I don’t know what this would entail about the motivic analogues.

Comment: @EricPeterson If this were true motivically for $k$ a subfield of $\mathbb{C}$, it would also be true classically by applying Betti realization to the diagram. Probably some finiteness argument can also allow you to reduce from a general field of characteristic 0 to a subfield of $\mathbb{C}$.

Answer (score 7):

**NO** such a map does not exist.

Thanks to Eric Peterson for making me realize that the argument carries through even if the map is not a map of algebras.

By [rigidity](http://folk.uio.no/paularne/rigidityma.pdf),you can only consider the case where $k$ is a subfield of $\mathbb{C}$, so I will restrict myself to this case.

---

If there were such a map, then it would exist also after Betti realization. Hence there would be a map of spectra $H\mathbb{Z}→MU$ such that the precomposition with the unit $\mathbb{S}→H\mathbb{Z}$ is the unit $\mathbb{S}→MU$. But then, postcomposing with the standard cotruncation map $MU→H\mathbb{Z}$ (this is just an avatar of the ring map $E→Hπ_0E$ existing for every connective ring spectrum) we would have a map $H\mathbb{Z}→H\mathbb{Z}$ that is the unit when precomposed with $\mathbb{S}→H\mathbb{Z}$. Since endomorphisms of $H\mathbb{Z}$ are determined by the value on $\pi_0$, it follows that the composition $H\mathbb{Z}→MU→H\mathbb{Z}$ must be the identity. In particular $H\mathbb{Z}$ would be a retract of $MU$.

However this is false: in fact $MU→H\mathbb{Z}$ factors through connective $K$-theory $ku$, so in particular the bottom cell of $ku$ would split off. But we know that the first k-invariant of $ku$ is nontrivial (it is in fact the Milnor invariant).

Comment: @Tsk Can you be more precise about the situation? What map from the sphere spectrum to $Σ^{a,b}MGL$ are we talking about here?

Comment: I think you should ask it as a separate question, but if the map realizes to a nontrivial class in $π_nMU$ I believe a variant of the same reasoning should still work.

Comment: I can't follow the last part of your answer. What is the contradiction if $H\mathbb{Z}$ is a retract of $MU$?

Comment: @user438991 If $H\mathbb{Z}$ is a retract of $MU$, then it is also a retract of $ku$ (the retraction is just the composite $H\mathbb{Z}→MU→ku$). In particular the fiber sequence $Σ^2ku→ku→H\mathbb{Z}$ would split, but this is impossible since after applying mod 2 cohomology it doesn't split as a module over the Steenrod algebra.